# Binding two divs to two click events when one is contained within the other

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

$('#outer').click(function() { alert ("outer"); });
$('#inner').click(function() { alert ("inner"); });
```

The inner does get called, but the other gets called as well. I want to do an either-or situation. Can you advise on a better way to get around this problem so that I can click my inner div successfully without triggering my outer div click event?

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Squ9m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('#outer').click(function() { alert ("outer"); });
$('#inner').click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); alert ("inner"); });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Squ9m/2/).

You could also use `return false`:

```
$('#outer').click(function() { alert("outer"); });
$('#inner').click(function(event) { alert("inner"); return false; });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Squ9m/4/).

`return false;` is the equivalent of using `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`; the first example is useful, then, if you wanted to retain the default function of the element that was clicked, without allowing that event to bubble up the DOM tree.

References:

- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the event to the method that fires for the inner div and then tell it to stop propagation.

```
$('#inner').click(function(event) { alert("inner"); event.stopPropagation();});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Squ9m/3/)